# MVVM Separation of Concerns in Import/Using Statement

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, entity-framework, mvvm

I have been trying to adhere to the MVVM Pattern, but then I come across something that I'm unsure about.

Let me build the scenario. I have an entity framework project and my main project. I build a Manager Class for the ef object that handles all the LINQ statements. As Expected I need to Import the EF Model into this manager class. However, when I pass the ViewModel the objects from the manager I also have to Import the EF Model into the ViewModel.

It seems like this actually goes against the MVVM Pattern. Is there something that I am missing? Most of what I have read basically says that you follow MVVM upto a point until its just easier to break it.

So here is the Manager Class

```
Imports ProjectManagerDbConnect
Public Class PMDB_BillingPeriods_Manager
Public Function GetLast12Periods() As List(Of BillingPeriod)
    Using ds As New PMEntities
        Dim qry = From p In ds.BillingPeriods
                  Order By p.BillPeriod Descending
                  Select p

        Dim billingPeriodList As List(Of BillingPeriod) = New List(Of BillingPeriod)(qry.Take(12).ToList())
        Return billingPeriodList
    End Using


End Function
End Class
```

And the ViewModel Class

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel
Imports ProjectManagerDbConnect
Public Class BillingPeriodViewModel
Inherits CommonBase

Public Sub New()
    Try
        loadLast12Period()
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub

Private mPeriods As ObservableCollection(Of BillingPeriod)
Public Property Periods() As ObservableCollection(Of BillingPeriod)
    Get
        Return mPeriods
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As ObservableCollection(Of BillingPeriod))
        mPeriods = value
        RaisePropertyChanged("Periods")
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub loadLast12Period()
    Dim mgr As New PMDB_BillingPeriods_Manager
    Periods = New ObservableCollection(Of BillingPeriod)(mgr.GetLast12Periods)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please show an example. Use fake models - we don't care what's actually in yours. Just enough to demonstrate the issue, please.

Comment: Hmm, Why would my post be edited to remove the 'Thank you' at the end?

Comment: Because [so] is not a discussion forum. Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: I've done much more MVC than MVVM, but should the ViewModel constructor be doing any work? Why not let the code which instantiates the ViewModel pass in the result of calling `mgr.GetLast12Periods`. That way, the ViewModel doesn't even need to know about the manager class.

Comment: I'm in no way an expert, but the class that instantiates the viewModel would be the view. So in that case you would be passing the mgr down one further level. This would create the view knowing about the viewModel and the manager. Unless this is my problem all along.

Comment: Ok, in that case, my only comment is that you should get rid of that try/catch in the constructor. You don't want to hide exceptions from yourself and not know they're occurring.

Comment: Unfortunately, when working with WPF and connections the design time won't render without some type of Design/Run type logic. This is certainly not the prettiest way to do it, but I really don't need design time data.

Comment: Yeah, but that also hides the exception at runtime. At least try to log the exception, but yeah, put the _logging_ inside a try/catch block so that if it fails at design time, you're ok.